# How to view qos statistics on cisco 6500?

Tags: cisco, qos

We have a 6504 switch with supervisor 720 10GE as core/distribution. We do marking at access level on 2960. I see drops on core. So I need to know about something like *mls qos int stat*, but on 6500. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few to try-

`show queueing interface xxx`

`show mls qos detailed`

`show int st`  (generally useful to see that everything is fast switched)

`show interfaces utilization xxx`

if applied, the `show policy-map` and `show class-map` may also give useful information.

It's less likely as an issue, but the various fabric stats can also provide some info.  Go for `show fabric utilization`, `show fabric channel-counters` among others.